# Is the view name inferred from the request path or from the string returned from the request handling method in Spring4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

First, have a look at where the jsp is residing, ***/WEB-INF/views/***

[image]

***Case a)*** with ***RequestParam***
Consider the snippet - controller class:

```
@Controller
public class SpittleController {

    private SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpittleController(SpittleRepository spittleRepository) {

        this.spittleRepository = spittleRepository;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/spittles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String spittles(Model model, @RequestParam("max") long max,
                           @RequestParam("count") int count) {

        model.addAttribute("spittleList",spittleRepository.findSpittles(max, count));

        //return "spittles";
        return null;                // Note this, I returned NULL
    }   
}
```

And I see the result as:
[image]

Now consider returning a ***String*** than a ***null***,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spittles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String spittles(Model model, @RequestParam("max") long max,
                       @RequestParam("count") int count) {

    model.addAttribute("spittleList",spittleRepository.findSpittles(max, count));

    return "spittles";

}
```

and the O/P reflected as:

[image]

***Caseb)*** with ***PathVariable***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spittles/{spittleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String spittles(Model model, @PathVariable("spittleId") long spittleId) {

           System.out.println("HERE: "+spittleId);
        model.addAttribute("spittleList",spittleRepository.findOne(spittleId));

        return null;
    }
```

I returned ***null*** as shown above.
***O/P*** reflected as:

[image]

First of all, what is this as shown in the above figure:

> ***/WEB-INF/views/spittles/1.jsp***

Now I returned the string "spittles" and it starts to work fine.

[image]

Can someone tell me why the difference in case of ***RequestParam*** and ***PathVariable***, both for   ***null*** and ***"spittles"*** returned values?

I see myself struggled a lot when it comes to ***URL resolution***. Any suggestions to guide me on how to work with ***URL's*** would be very nice?

The question is not asking for how the ***view name gets resolved*** but rather why the ***difference*** in case of ***@RequestParam*** and ***@PathVariable***?

Comment: See my answer to my other post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434194/relation-b-w-view-name-in-the-controller-method-and-requestmappingvalue

Comment: @Alexander: THere is a clear differnce b/w these 2 questions raised separately.